# Transiting through Paris CDG from USA to non-EU

Tags: transit, covid-19, cdg, air-france

A citizen of country `X` (non-EU, non-Schengen, transit visa is not required) is travelling from the USA to country `X` with a connection in Paris Charles de Gaulle. The airline is Air France and the ticket is "integrated" -- both flights to CDG and from CDG are on the same reservation. So presumably going through immigration in CDG is not needed.

Question: according to the current regulations, is negative PCR test required in order to board the flight for France?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of November 12, 2020, https://www.parisaeroport.fr/passagers/les-vols/covid-19-informations-voyageurs :

> Passagers en correspondance à Paris
>
> Les aéroports parisiens sont ouverts et accueillent les passagers en
> correspondance entre deux vols.
>
> Vous devez vous assurer avant votre départ de l'aéroport d'origine de
> disposer du test de moins de 48h ou 72h exigé selon le pays de
> destination finale.
>
> > Passengers connecting in Paris
> >
> > Parisian airports are open and welcome passengers connecting between two flights.
> >
> > You must ensure before your departure from the airport of origin that you have the required test of less than 48 hours or 72 hours depending on the country of final destination.

It seems you are requested to present a negative PCR test if your end destination requires it.